# Spring Webflow compatible jars

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-webflow

I am using Spring 2.5 framework, what is the compatible webflow jars?

Answer (score 2):

If your version is **Spring 2.5.6** use Spring WebFlow 2.0.xx otherwise (**Spring 2.5**) use Spring WebFlow 1.0.xx